# Showing line numbers in Glue Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, config, aws-glue

How is it possible that there is no shortcut for this function in AWS Glue?,
is really necessary for debugging code and find the line of code was break , i dont see any buttom for this.

I need to know if there is a shortcut to show cell numbers

Answer (score 0):

Well easy peace with <kbd>Ctrl-Shift+C</kbd> can be open a menu o many configurations also include change default Jupyter's Theme
[image]

[image]